# Analytical Organic Chemistry - Do you agree with my answer to this C-13 NMR question?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Question 2b:

> [image: ![][1]][1]]

Because of the 184.7 signal, I think it's either an ester or carboxylic acid. There isn't a DEPT signal based on 184.7 because the carbon is not bonded to any hydrogens. Since there are some carbons not being shown, I figure there is probably some symmetry going on. From what I know, the DEPT (+) signs indicate the presence of either a CH or CH3.  Since it's kind of hard to make a symmetric ester, I settled on the molecule: methylpropanoic acid. The 2 methyl groups at the end of the chain are symmetric, being represented by 1 peak.

Do you agree with this reasoning?

Comment: First, this is a homework question. You should show your effort to solve this problem , thus, we can geet involve helping you. You have shown effort in the problem 2a (I believe since your values are not given), but part of that is completely wrong. For example, look at the reasoning given for no peaks shown in DEPT spectrum. Please show your honest effort and show reasonable reasoning. So far, I see at least no knowledge of DEPT in you!

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Good analysis. But it's just not methylpropanoic acid (yout naming is incorrect). It is 2-methylpropanoic acid.